# Optimise MongoDB aggregate query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection with millions of documents, each document represent an event: {_id, product, timestamp}
In my query, I need to group by product and take the top 10 for example.

```
"aggregate" : "product_events",
    "pipeline" : [
        {
            "$match" : {
                "timeEvent" : {
                    "$gt" : ISODate("2017-07-17T00:00:00Z")
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "$group" : {
                "_id" : "$product",
                "count" : {
                    "$sum" : 1
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "$sort" : {
                "count" : -1
            }
        },
        {
            "$limit" : 10
        }
    ]
```

My query is very slow now (10 seconds), I am wondering if there is a way to store data differently to optimise this query?

```
db.product_events.explain("executionStats").aggregate([ {"$match" : 
{"timeEvent" : {"$gt" : ISODate("2017-07-17T00:00:00Z")}}},{"$group" : 
{"_id" : "$product","count" : {"$sum" : 1}}}, {"$project": {"_id": 1, 
"count": 1}} , {"$sort" : {"count" : -1}},{"$limit" : 500}], 
{"allowDiskUse": true})
{
"stages" : [
    {
        "$cursor" : {
            "query" : {
                "timeEvent" : {
                    "$gt" : ISODate("2017-07-17T00:00:00Z")
                }
            },
            "fields" : {
                "product" : 1,
                "_id" : 0
            },
            "queryPlanner" : {
                "plannerVersion" : 1,
                "namespace" : "mydb.product_events",
                "indexFilterSet" : false,
                "parsedQuery" : {
                    "timeEvent" : {
                        "$gt" : ISODate("2017-07-17T00:00:00Z")
                    }
                },
                "winningPlan" : {
                    "stage" : "COLLSCAN",
                    "filter" : {
                        "timeEvent" : {
                            "$gt" : ISODate("2017-07-17T00:00:00Z")
                        }
                    },
                    "direction" : "forward"
                },
                "rejectedPlans" : [ ]
            },
            "executionStats" : {
                "executionSuccess" : true,
                "nReturned" : 2127315,
                "executionTimeMillis" : 940,
                "totalKeysExamined" : 0,
                "totalDocsExamined" : 2127315,
                "executionStages" : {
                    "stage" : "COLLSCAN",
                    "filter" : {
                        "timeEvent" : {
                            "$gt" : ISODate("2017-07-17T00:00:00Z")
                        }
                    },
                    "nReturned" : 2127315,
                    "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 810,
                    "works" : 2127317,
                    "advanced" : 2127315,
                    "needTime" : 1,
                    "needYield" : 0,
                    "saveState" : 16620,
                    "restoreState" : 16620,
                    "isEOF" : 1,
                    "invalidates" : 0,
                    "direction" : "forward",
                    "docsExamined" : 2127315
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$group" : {
            "_id" : "$product",
            "count" : {
                "$sum" : {
                    "$const" : 1
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$project" : {
            "_id" : true,
            "count" : true
        }
    },
    {
        "$sort" : {
            "sortKey" : {
                "count" : -1
            },
            "limit" : NumberLong(500)
        }
    }
],
"ok" : 1
}
```

Below my indexes

```
db.product_events.getIndexes()
[
{
    "v" : 2,
    "key" : {
        "_id" : 1
    },
    "name" : "_id_",
    "ns" : "mydb.product_events"
},
{
    "v" : 2,
    "key" : {
        "product" : 1,
        "timeEvent" : -1
    },
    "name" : "product_1_timeEvent_-1",
    "ns" : "mydb.product_events"
}
]
```

Comment: Have an `index` for `product` as well as `timeEvent` and see in `explain()` object how its impacting your results and then share your findings.

Comment: Yes, I do have already an index on product and timeEvent

Comment: Then, do post the `explain(executionStats)` results here without which its impossible to figure out whats going wrong.

Comment: Yes, I have just posted it

Comment: From the `executionStats`, its clear that your indexes are not being utilized for the query, it does collection scan instead of index scan. Please post output of `getIndexes()` also.

Comment: I have added the indexes

Answer (score 0):

Creating indexes on fields of a collection aids into optimising process of data retrieval from database collections.

Indexes are generally created on fields into which data are filtered according to specific criteria.

Data contained into indexed fields are sorted in specific order and while fetching data once match is found ,scanning of other document stops which makes  process of fetching data faster.

According to description as mentioned into above question to optimise performance of aggregate query please try creating an index on timeEvent field as timeEvent field is used as a filter expression into $match stage of aggregation pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-compound/#create-a-compound-index) on compound indexes states the following.

> db.products.createIndex( { "item": 1, "stock": 1 } )
>
> **The order of the fields listed in a compound index is important.** The
> index will contain references to documents sorted first by the values
> of the item field and, within each value of the item field, sorted by
> values of the stock field.
>
> In addition to supporting queries that match on all the index fields,
> compound indexes can support queries that match on the prefix of the
> index fields. **That is, the index supports queries on the item field as
> well as both item and stock fields**.

Your `product_1_timeEvent_-1` index looks like this:

```
{
    "product" : 1,
    "timeEvent" : -1
}
```

which is why it cannot be used to support a query that only filters on `timeEvent`.

Options you have to get that sorted:

- Flip the order of the fields in your index
- Remove the `product` field from your index
- Create an additional index with only the `timeEvent` field in it.
- (Include some additional filter on the `product` field so the existing index gets used)

And keep in mind that any creation/deletion/modification of an index may impact other queries, too. So make sure you test your changes properly.